# Why would external Storage Location be unavailable in Play Music and Play Movies?

Tags: google-play-store, external-sd, google-play-music, profiles, google-play-movies

I have a Galaxy Tab S running Android 5.0.2. I also have a 32GB SD card installed. Supposedly I should be able to set Play Music and Play Movies to download to the external card, but those options are not available for some reason.

In Play Music Settings, I see the **Storage location** option, but it's set to "Internal (on this device)" and it is disabled (greyed out); tapping does nothing to change it. In Play Movies, there is no option at all in Settings nor when I tap to download a rented or purchased movie.

I see plenty of referneces online about people being able to set the storage location for both apps, as of Android 4.4 and above, so I'm confused why I can't get it on my Lollipop 5.0.2 tablet.

I've confirmed that I can write to the SD card; I've done so via the Android File Transfer app from my laptop, as well as using the Samsung My File app installed on the tablet.

Update: I just noticed that this happens only for *some* of the user profiles on the device. The "owner" profile can set the storage locations to external (SD card) but no other user profile can.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on my Lenovo P70A on Android 4.4 and 5.x as well.

**The solution for me was to manually create the folder "com.google.android.music" under the "/Android/data" folder on my external SD card**, which is where Google Play Music normally stores the downloaded (offline) music. Once I've done this and force closed Google Play Music, starting it again it resulted in the External Storage option becoming available.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. How is your sdcard called? Mine is `/Removable/MicroSD`